# Is there a way to continuous loop between two fullscreens programs?

Tags: windows-7

At work we have a monitor that constantly loops between a powerpoint presentation but now they are asking for it to also cycle through this website that is on accessible through internet explorer is there a way to could do this? This is on a computer running windows 7

Comment: OP last seen one day after posting this question a year ago; unlikely to return, I imagine

Answer (score 2):

Even if there is not a dedicated app, I would recommend a [macro recorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_recorder).

Just record `alt-tab` with a pause, and replay it in a loop.

---

Better, if you can code even a little would be to use [Auto-it](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) and write maximum 5 lines of code.